# git commit -a bypasses git hook when it shouldn't

Tags: git, githooks

I have a git hook for commit-msg which works quite happily when I run

```
git commit -m "MSG HERE"
```

but if I run

```
git commit -a
```

Which triggers committing using your text editor it skips the hook.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

My hook is as follows

```
#!/bin/bash
if ! egrep -q 'DAVE-[0-9]+' $1 ; then
     echo "No Jira Issue Number found" >&2
     exit 1
fi

if [[ "$(wc -c $1 | awk '{print $1}')" -le 20 ]] ; then
     echo "Commit message too short" >&2
     exit 1
fi
```

Comment: What is your hook? Testing with the default hook, which detects duplicate Signed-off-by lines, it triggers just fine when running `git commit -a`: after entering duplicate lines, I get an error message.

Comment: I've updated the question with a copy of the git hook, Thanks

Comment: What version of Git are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your problem, so my guess here is that there's a misunderstanding -- the `commit-msg` hook runs *after* you specified your message, ie. after you close the commit text editor, not before, so you will only notice the changes in your `git log`.

EDIT:

Are you sure you're not counting comment lines? These would easily blow up the message to above 20 characters. Use something like `cat $1|grep -vE '^#'|wc -c|awk ...`.

Comment: The commit-msg I wrote prevents git commit under certain situations, for example if the commit message is less than 20 characters, it will stop the commit from happening

Comment: Ah, are you sure you're not counting comment lines? These would easily blow up the message to above 20 characters. Use something like `cat $1|grep -vE '^#'|wc -c|awk ...`.

Comment: Can you `echo` somethig inside your script so you can make sure it's not run? Can you echo the byte count, just to check? Does it match your expectation?

Comment: Okay I echo a string but and it ran so now I'm curious in what it see's as $i , thanks

Comment: do you mean `$1`? that should be a temporary file, or something like `./.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG`, usually. OS?