# Git-hook: No staged changes when running `git commit -a`

Tags: git, githooks, clang-format

Here's my (simplified, no error checking) git hook:

```
git diff --cached | clang-format-diff -p1 > $PATCHFILE
git patch-apply -p0 $PATCHFILE           # modify the working tree
git patch-apply -p0 --cached $PATCHFILE  # modify what is staged
```

This works fine, however, when a user is running `git commit -a`, the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#_examples) to `git diff` informs me that "there are various ways to check your working tree":

> ```
> $ git diff            (1)
> $ git diff --cached   (2)
> $ git diff HEAD       (3)
> ```
>
> Changes in the working tree not yet staged for the next commit.
>
> Changes between the index and your last commit; **what you would be committing if you run "git commit" without "-a" option**.
>
> Changes in the working tree since your last commit; **what you would be committing if you run "git commit -a"**

As a consequence, the script does not work when a using is `git commit -a`. This is because it gets called at a stage where the index apparently has not had the changes added.

I would like to apply the clang-format-diff changes only on staged files.

## Question:

1. Why, apparently, does `git commit -a` call the pre-commit hook before staging files? Isn't that a bug?
2. What should I do? Can I somehow detect inside the pre-commit hook that I am inside a `git commit -a` situation? I would rather avoid formatting unstaged changes.

### Notes

- I am using git 2.11.0.
- Related questions but not duplicate:

  - [git commit -a bypasses git hook when it shouldn't](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27983784/461597)
  - [`git diff` does not work when run from a git pre-commit hook](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45721633/461597)
  - [git pre-commit hook not running when running git commit -a](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45749689/461597)

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45722437/1256452) (not the accepted answer) to your second related question. Ultimately it's very difficult to deal correctly with an alternative index. A clang-formatting pre-commit hook I use includes the test: `if [ $GIT_INDEX_FILE != ".git/index" ]; then echo "Error: Non-default index file is being used (GIT_INDEX_FILE is set)." >&2; ...` and simply refuses to allow commits with `-a` or path arguments.

Comment: Thank you @torek for that excellent answer you wrote. I think I can do better than not allowing git commit --include or --all. And GIT_INDEX_FILE seems to be the answer.

Comment: You can indeed use `GIT_INDEX_FILE`, but now you have to account for two cases: what happens if the commit goes forward and completes, and what happens if it aborts? In the "abort" case the temporary index is discarded. In the "completes" case, consider how the temporary index and the original index interact. It gets tricky; I have not worked out all the details; it seems like it should be possible, but I have not had time to work on it.